# What happens if the bounty is answered by the asker with another answer with 2 upvotes?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I busted myself to figure out a user's problem and solve it, in [How can I convert image binary from API call to data URI in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394721/how-can-i-convert-image-binary-from-api-call-to-data-uri-in-javascript) I got 2 upvotes. Using my response basis, the asker answered his own question and marked it as best answer.

At the time of expiration, will I be getting the bounty or not?

Comment: It's up to the OP. He can choose to give it to anyone, or no one. If he chooses no one, then Community will give half of it to you (unless someone posts an answer that scores even higher than yours, which seems unlikely).